# how to get started with Chef cookbook?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have followed below mentioned article to configure apache, mysql, php using chef cookbook.

http://gettingstartedwithchef.com/first-steps-with-chef.html

My purpose was to write a standalone application, which will do all needed setup for mysql, apache, php etc.

By following the article, I observed they are executing the chef commands to install stuffs & getting modifying the configuration files manually.

for example for the following command I wrote respective ruby equivalent:

```
 rvm install ruby-2.1.2
ruby equivalent : `rvm install ruby-2.1.2`
```

Similar way, I found alternatives for the shell commands & prepared my ruby code.

I am not sure whether that's the right approach.

2nd: how we can do custom functionality, let's say bundling a gemfile inside a project repo or running rails migrations. 
How to perform those operations, please guide.

Answer (score 0):

There're many community created cookbooks for many applications.
You can find many cookbooks on [chef supermarket](https://supermarket.chef.io/).

In general, you can install packet by use your packet manager this way:
For another supported install options you can look to cookbook.

```
    package "#{res_name} :create nginx" do
      package_name 'nginx'
      action :install
    end
```

If you want install ruby rvm package, you can use [gem_package](https://docs.chef.io/resource_gem_package.html) statement:

```
    gem_package 'name' do
      clear_sources              TrueClass, FalseClass
      gem_binary                 String
      notifies                   # see description
      options                    String
      package_name               String, Array # defaults to 'name' if         not specified
      provider                   Chef::Provider::Package::Rubygems
      source                     String
      subscribes                 # see description
      timeout                    String, Integer
      version                    String, Array
      action                     Symbol # defaults to :install if not specified
    end
```